# Hide view actions in action bar if no document selected in view in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

how do I hide actions in the action bar if the view is empty?

I need it for example for actions like "edit" or "open". This makes only sense to show these actions when I have already selected one document from the view.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by enabling the view option "Evaluate actions for every document change"

[image: Evaluate actions for every document change]

Additionally you have to set a hide-when formula for every action. For example you can check the document form field to detect if a document has been selected. The hide when can look like this:
Hide action if formula is true: Form != "document" (if your form name is document).

Check out this link for further details: 
http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tips.nsf/tipsview/15C228C795F2A1478525712200545A0F

One caveat is that the action bar will not be hidden consistantly - it seems to depend on the evaluation on view open. So it can happen that the view action bar will not be displayed and later be displayed (or vice versa).

Comment: feel free to provide more details... e.g. under which conditions does it work or not